# Manga where male MC befriends all kinds of mythical creatures, even gods

Tags: story-identification, manga

This manga has been stuck in my head but I just can’t remember the name. If you think of a similar manga but something doesn’t match, just put it down please, as I could be wrong about something.

Things I know:

- Male Main Character
- Not only humans in world
- MC befriends all kind of people
- *At least* three gods
- One god guy and two girl gods (there might be more, I don’t remember)
- Gods don’t have the old people look
- The gods don’t stay in “heaven”, they come down to earth
- One of the girl gods stays in her “heaven”, because when she goes around humans (and others) they get an overwhelming sense of death or fear
- MC manages to overcome the feeling just enough to interact with the girl god (I think a handshake)

Things I think happened but am not sure about:

- MC stays with a noble family of some rank
- Girl from the noble family he’s staying with, acts as his guardian (I think)
- They get surprised every time he befriends somebody (I think because their race is usually hard to befriend or rare to find)
- Wanted to have him avoid meeting the girl god who radiates fear/death
- Girl god befriends MC because he was able to… shake her hand?
- Girl guardian is surprised by the girl god and MC friendship

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Was the introduction of Japanese cooking a part of the plotline? I know it sounds weird, but I can think of at least one manga where that was part of how he went befriending the gods, and other creatures.

Answer (score 2):

Is this ***[I Got Caught Up In a Hero Summons, but the Other World was at Peace!](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/i-got-caught-up-in-a-hero-summons-but-the-other-world-was-at-peace)***...?

> When you get summoned to another world, things are supposed to go a certain way: become a hero, battle monsters, and slay demons, right? But when Kaito gets his summons, things are a little different. First off, he’s not even the hero…but it doesn’t matter, because the world he’s been thrust into is at peace. With nothing better to do, Kaito finds himself taking it easy in this unexpectedly mellow fantasy world. Now he can breakfast with its beautiful denizens, learn magic with the help of a spunky demon girl, go to barbeques, and so much more!

The protagonist, Miyama Kaito, is a college student who's inadvertently caught up in a hero summoning and transported to a kingdom in another world. The duchess of the kingdom apologises and explains that she won't be able to send him home for another year, but that she'll pay for his accommodation in the meantime.

This world contains three realms: the human realm, the realm of the gods, and the realm of demons. Humans and demons have been at peace since the Demon King was defeated 100 years prior, so interactions between humans and demons are now commonplace, while interactions between humans and gods are quite rare.

During his stay in this world, Kaito meets a number of female gods and demons, such as the God of Creation, the God of Time, and the Underworld King. Each of them takes an unusually strong interest in him, due to his 'Sympathy Magic,' which enables him to interact with such beings on a level that most humans can't.

In chapter 14, he encounters the Death King, whose 'Death Magic' instils overwhelming fear in people around her, and can even knock them unconscious. Being near her makes Kaito want to run for his life, but due to his Sympathy Magic, he's able to adapt to this and force himself to stand his ground and shake her hand.

[image]

[image]