# Manga where mc was summoned to another world accidently where there is no demon lord but he meets with white haired goddess,death God & world tree god

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The main character was summoned accidently to another world where there is no demon lord. He meets with death God, white haired goddess and world tree god.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, what was the main character's name? How was he summoned? Did he die first? Why was there no Demon Lord? Does he get given powers? What is the setting of the world (modern, medieval, fantasy)? Was this aimed at adults (with sex/nudity/gore/violence) or a general audience? What were the names of the gods? How and where did he meet with them? Was this in colour or black-and-white? What did the cover look like? What was the art style? What colour was the protagonist's hair? What age was he? What happened *after* he'd been summoned?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Possibly [I Got Caught Up In a Hero Summons, but the Other World was at Peace!](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/275537). The question and answer mentions multiple gods, although not a "world tree" god. I haven't read it so I can't confirm either way.

Comment: @qazmlpok Thanks bro

Answer (score 2):

As confirmed in the comments, this is *[I Got Caught Up In a Hero Summons, but the Other World was at Peace!](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/i-got-caught-up-in-a-hero-summons-but-the-other-world-was-at-peace)*.

> When you get **summoned to another world**, things are supposed to go a certain way: become a hero, battle monsters, and slay demons, right? But when Kaito gets his summons, things are a little different. First off, he’s not even the hero…but it doesn’t matter, because the world he’s been thrust into is at peace. With nothing better to do, Kaito finds himself taking it easy in this unexpectedly mellow fantasy world. Now he can breakfast with its beautiful denizens, learn magic with the help of a spunky demon girl, go to barbeques, and so much more!

The title alludes to it, but as the other world is at peace, there is no demon king. There are also a number of gods that the protagonists meets. Borrowing from the [other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/275543):

This world contains three realms: the human realm, the realm of the gods, and the realm of demons. Humans and demons have been at peace since the Demon King was defeated 100 years prior, so interactions between humans and demons are now commonplace, while interactions between humans and gods are quite rare.

During his stay in this world, Kaito meets a number of female gods and demons, such as the God of Creation, the God of Time, and the Underworld King. Each of them takes an unusually strong interest in him, due to his 'Sympathy Magic,' which enables him to interact with such beings on a level that most humans can't.

In chapter 14, he encounters the Death King, whose 'Death Magic' instils overwhelming fear in people around her, and can even knock them unconscious. Being near her makes Kaito want to run for his life, but due to his Sympathy Magic, he's able to adapt to this and force himself to stand his ground and shake her hand.

[image]